# How to set up Quorum Blockchain?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, quorum

I have read a lot about Quorum blockchain. My goal is to run and test it. I have found many articles. Could anyone suggest me good start-up articles for setting-up the Quorum on a number of nodes and test it with smart contracts?

Comment: @ Mohamed https://medium.com/@shizekun/how-to-set-up-a-quorum-private-chain-with-raft-consensus-and-dynamic-membership-bf826f3927e5

Answer (score 3):

In the Quorum Wiki is a technical step for step setup Guide  [link](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/wiki/From-Scratch)

If you want to jump the initial Network setup and want to test quroum direktly, you could use ["Quorum Maker"](https://github.com/synechron-finlabs/quorum-maker) to quickly spin up a Test Network and test your Smart contracts there.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to quickly get up and running with quorum, I'd suggest using the [7-nodes example](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples). That will set up a network of 7 nodes running on your local machine. It even gives you a number of different virtual machine deployment options.
You can then play around and get familiar using that.